# How to implement expressions in Generic Repository?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, lambda

I am working on a .Net core project and I have 5 look up tables, so instead of making repository and service for each one I want to make generic repository and generic service for them.

My problem is in implementing `FindByID` using expressions. I understand the idea behind it but I don't know where or how to use. Any help would be appreciated

Generic Repository Function

```
    private readonly NexusContext _context;
    IMapper _mapper;
    public GenericRepository(NexusContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
  public  GenericLookupDTO GetById(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var obj =  _context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        var objMapped = AutoMapping.mapper.Map<GenericLookupDTO>(obj);
        return objMapped;
     }
```

Service Function

```
      private readonly IGenericRepository<T> _genericRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public ConfigurationService(IGenericRepository<T> genericRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this._genericRepository = genericRepository;
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

         List<Errors> errors = new List<Errors>();
        try
        {
            var obj =  _genericRepository.GetById(predicate);
            if (obj == null)
            {
                errors.Add(new Errors("404", "Couldn't find configration"));
                return new GenericResponse<GenericLookupDTO>(errors, new GenericLookupDTO());

            }
            await _unitOfWork.CompleteAsync();
            return new GenericResponse<GenericLookupDTO>("1", "Success", obj);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errors.Add(new Errors(ex.HResult.ToString(), ex.InnerException.Message));
            return new GenericResponse<GenericLookupDTO>(errors, new GenericLookupDTO());
        }
```

Controller function

```
    private readonly IConfigurationService<LutNationality> _configurationService;
    public NationalityController(IConfigurationService<LutNationality> configurationService)
    {
        this._configurationService = configurationService;
    }
    [HttpGet("Id")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(GenericLookupDTO), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdAsync()
    {
        var result = await _configurationService.GetByIdAsync(//what should i pass here);
        if (result.operationSuccess)
            return Ok(result);
        return BadRequest(result);
    }
```

First look up Table

```
public partial class LutGender
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Second look up Table

```
public partial class LutNationality
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Generic DTO

```
public class GenericLookupDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you make the lookups inherit from one base class? Maybe you should show two of them for clarity. And how do you imagine the parametrization? I guess that `GetByIdAsync` should somehow indicate *which* lookup is requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository pattern is already implemented by the `DbSet<T>` and consists in few operations over your entity to store and retrive him from an abstracted data store. Just your entity, it's very important on DDD.

But, I know that sometimes we need to put another layer of abstraction over this, to deal with another databases like nosql, for example.

In this case, usually we create a gereneric repository, and it's needed to supply a way to make operations based on what type this repository is. To accomplish this, we need to define a common interface for our entities with an Id and implement this on those entities:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    Guid Id (get; set;}
}
```

That way, constraining your generic repository to this type of interface provides you ability to access the Id on the methods.

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
private readonly NexusContext _context;
IMapper _mapper;
public GenericRepository(NexusContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

public  GenericLookupDTO GetById(Guid id)
{
    var obj =  _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id = id);
    var objMapped = AutoMapping.mapper.Map<GenericLookupDTO>(obj);
    return objMapped;
 }
```

}

I really recomend you to don't return DTOs from repository, if you need to aggregate data from many different entities that are not related, use a different layer of data access, very simplified, and create freely your own queries, using dapper or even EF but projecting directly DTOs.
If the DTO is identical of an entity, in this case use the repository to retrieve the entity and on application layer map this entity to a DTO.

When you have time, take a look at DDD principles to clarify a little bit more those subjects.

Back to your example, on the controller you will need to inject the right type of generic repository, like:

```
IGenericRepository<Customer> customerRepository
```

and configure your dependecy injection container to resolve generic types, like:

```
services.AddTransient<IGenericRepository<>, GenericRepository<>>();
```

The service will rely just on `IGenericRepository<T>` as you did.

But, if you want to query freely your entities, I recommend you make use of OData or GraphQl, that will provides you more control over queries.

I'm tried to be very simplistic here, so, I hope that i could clarify things a little bit more for you!

Comment: Use Find instead of FirstOrDefault.